# Seeding/migrating hasMany relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, one-to-many

I wan't to seed an "One To Many" relation.

Product model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
}
```

Order model

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'orders';

    /**
     * Products by order.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}
```

Product migration

```
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->integer('stock');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

Order migration

```
class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            // refers to a user table
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users');

            // "One To Many" relation???
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('orders');
    }
}
```

Product seeder

```
class ProductsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('products')->insert([
            'name' => 'EEE PC',
            'stock' => 20
        ]);
    }
}
```

Order seeder

```
class OrdersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('orders')->insert([
            'user_id' => 1
            // "One To Many" relation???
        ]);
    }
}
```

Do I need to create a join table like "order_product" or something? I'm confused because in the order model, the `hasMany` refers to **Product**

**An order have products, but every product can be used in in different orders!**

Answer (score 0):

The relation between product and order should be [`many-to-many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and you should create a new table `order_product` with columns:

```
id | order_id | product_id
```

Follow the Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) it will help you to solve your problem. If you are stuck anywhere then SO is there to help you.